# Почему отрицательные числа не проходят проверку isdigit()

Tags: python

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, почему в этом коде отрицательные числа не проходят проверку на то что они являются числами.

```
srt = [x for x in '-4 -5 +'.split()]
for i in srt:
    if i.isdigit():
        print(True)
```

Вывод: Пусто

---

А если я использую тоже самый код только с положительными числами

```
srt = [x for x in '4 5 +'.split()]
for i in srt:
    if i.isdigit():
        print(True)
```

Вывод : True True

---

Может кто то обьяснить почему так отрабатывает и как сделать проверку у отрицательных чисел?

Comment: ``.isdigit()`` переводится как "является цифрой", а не "является числом". Следовательно проверяет каждый символ поочередно, а не все значение целиком. Минус цифрой не является. Десятичный разделитель тоже, кстати.

Answer (score 2):

метод `isdigit` возвращает `True`, только если строка состоит полностью из цифр (`0123456789`)

можно попробовать реализовать свой `isdigit` с поддержкой отрицательных чисел

```
def isdigit(s):
    if s.startswith("-"):
        s = s[1:]
    return s.isdigit()
```

Comment: А как тогда сделать такую проверку у отрицательных чисел?

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать такую проверку:

```py
if i.lstrip("-").isdigit():
```

Подсмотрено на [английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28279773/8324991).